# es6 template string render element based on endpoint response

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I am rather new to ES6 and template literals etc... and was hoping to get some advice. I have an endpoint that gives me an array of objects that I am using to display certain student information. Within each object a student has a star rating. Long story short I want to take the rating number I get back from the endpoint and loop through that and display a star rating for them 1-5 stars. My endpoint and everything is working fine but I am struggling with outputting the html from the for loop. Any suggestions and or tips would be greatly appreciated.

**My es6 file contains the following:**

```
renderStudentRating = (studentRating) => {
  let rating = studentRating;

  for (let i = 0; i <= rating; i ++) {
    // should output an element based on rating count 
    <i class="student-star"></i>
  }
};

<span class="student-rating-info">
  <div id="rating">
    ${renderStudentRating(`${student.rating}`)}
  </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would create a span that has the appropriate number of stars.

```
renderStudentRating = studentRating => {
  let output = '';
  for (let i = 0; i <= studentRating; i ++) {
    // should output an element based on rating count 
    output += '<i class="student-star"></i>';
  }
  return output;
};
document.querySelector('.student-rating-container').innerHtml = `
    <span class="student-rating-info">
        <div id="rating">
            ${renderStudentRating(student.rating)}
        </div>
    </span>
`;
```